# how do i convert json with mixed type values to json with scala and json spray

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

I tried the tutorial of json spray but i have a different string where one value is a string and the other one is a list.
How do i convert the following string into a json object where each key is either a list or a string?

```
source = """{ "some": "JSON source", "kuku":["fu"] }"""
```

I wrote a short snipped of code but cannot continue from here:

```
val source = """{ "some": "JSON source", "kuku":["fu"] }"""
val jsonAst = source.asJson
val kuku = jsonAst.convertTo[?]
println(kuku)
```

If i cannot, how do i get the value of the key some(hopefully without regular expression)
I would prefer to avoid creating a specific object for it, because there are certain keys which can change.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the entire object to a map to an `Either`:

```
val jsonMap = jsonAst.convertTo[Map[String, Either[String, List[String]]]]
```

And then:

```
scala> println(jsonMap)
Map(some -> Left(JSON source), kuku -> Right(List(fu)))
```

The `Either` part explicitly models the fact that you don't know at compile-time which kind of value you'll get when you look up a key. There are lots of [introductions](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/11/either.html) to the idea of `Either` in Scala, but in short you can use it like this:

```
val some: String = jsonMap("some").left.getOrElse(
  ??? /* Provide a default value, throw an exception, etc. */
)

val kuku: List[String] = jsonMap("kuku").right.getOrElse(
  ??? /* Provide a default value, throw an exception, etc. */
)
```

Or, even better, handle the fact that the key might not exist at the same time:

```
val some: String = jsonMap.get("some").flatMap(_.left.toOption).getOrElse(
  ??? /* Provide a default value, throw an exception, etc. */
)
```

Alternatively you could navigate to the `"kuku"` field and then convert:

```
val kuku = jsonAst.asJsObject.getFields("kuku").headOption.map(
  _.convertTo[List[String]]
)
```

And then:

```
scala> kuku
res0: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(fu))
```

I personally find the first approach a little cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the great explaination. How do i get to the value "JSON source" without the Left? println(jsonMap.get("kuku").get) gives me Left("JSON source")

Comment: I've just added some comments about `Either`.